# JsonSerializerOptions doesn't work as expected

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization

I tried to use `builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>` to set the Serializer settings in the DI container.

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = false;
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
});
```

Let's consider the following endpoint to see if the settings are working:

```
app.MapPost("/product", (Product product) => $"Received {product}");
record Product(int Id, string Name, int Stock);
```

Product is not a simple type, so it is bound from the body of the request.

I played a little bit with postman to find the following:

[image]

This request produces the following body (of the response).

```
Received Product { Id = 0, Name = , Stock = 0 }
```

I don't understand what's happening. If the binding was not successful, the framework would throw an exception. It didn't throw an exception, but the values aren't set correctly (as we would expect).

It probably used the default value for the corresponding type.

Can you elaborate on that?

I expected that this case would be the only one working (passing a JSON in the following format `{"Id": 1, "Name": "Shoes", "Stock": 12}`), as `Id`, `Name`, `Stock` are the exact names that we used when defining the record. We used `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive=False`, so doesn't this make it necessary for us to write the property names exactly as we have in the class (record)?

Comment: Try using builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions

Comment: @davidfowl, the following JSON still doesn't work as expected: `{"Id": 1, "Name": "Shoes", "Stock": 12}`. What works is `{"id": 1, "name": "Shoes", "stock": 12}`. Can't figure out the reason. It's like it expects us to give the prop names in lower case which doesn't make sense to me given that we used `options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;`.

Comment: @davidfowl, if we set `options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;` everything works, but that's normal as we're basically telling the framework that it shouldn't care how the prop names are written in the JSON. I just thought that setting it to true should mean that all prop should be written in the JSON exactly as they are in the defining of the class/structure/record. So `Id`, `Name` and `Stock` in our case. Well, it seems that they can only be lower case in order for the serialization to work as expected.